# Hide error messages for Excel sheets with Powerquery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Is there a way to ignore popup error messages when refreshing an excel sheet with Powerquery (Workbook.RefreshAll).Sporadically I get an unexpected error during an automation and only when I confirm the message it continues to run.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

does not work.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Is the error caused by the PowerQuery or VBA?  What is the error - an _unexpected error_ describes pretty much every error possible.